# opencv black image after matchTemplate

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

As a result I am presented with a black image. I have tried to use convert with difference params like `out.convertTo(out,6)` but without success.

```
export function testAction(req, res) {
      req.file('image').upload((error, file) => {
        openCV.readImage(file[0].fd, function (err, im1) {
          let out = im1.matchTemplate(file[1].fd, 0);
          out.save('result.png');
        });
      });
      res.ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match template gives you float elements in Mat, and range [0;1].
When you saving the image it converts to CV_8UC3 image, but not scales properly.
You can try multiply your result by 255 and see, or use cv::normalize method.

Comment: @Eugene can you share how you did it?

Comment: just `out.normalize(0, 255, cv.Constants.CV_8UC3);`

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it's there is another answer.

`matchTemplate()` is synchronous so your code should be:

```
openCV.readImage(file[0].fd, function (err, im1) {
     im1.matchTemplate(file[1].fd, 0, function(out){
         out.save('result.png');
     })
})
```